# Axios Request - See All Objects in Response

Tags: node.js, angular, express, axios

I'm trying to run multiple API Requests and the display the data from all of them, I've tried it several different ways, but none of them contain ALL of the data from the requests.

Closest I've got (This contains all from the 2nd Request, and only the 'Name' from the first:

```
router.get('/summoner', (req, res) => {
  return axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/SUMMONERNAME', {
    headers: head
  })
  .then(summoner => {
    return axios.get('https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/SUMMONERID/summary?season=SEASON2017', {headers: head});
  })
  .then(summoner => {
    res.json(summoner.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Contains all data only from the FIRST call:

```
router.get('/summoner2', (req, res) => {

  axios.all([
    axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/SUMMONERNAME', {headers: head}),
    axios.get('https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/SUMMONERID/summary?season=SEASON2017', {headers: head})
  ])
  .then(axios.spread(function(summonerResponse, statsResponse){
    res.json(summonerResponse.data);
    res.json(statsResponse.data);
  }))
});
```

Contains all data only from the FIRST request:

```
router.get('/summoner3', (req, res) => {

  function getSummoner(){

    return axios.get('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/SUMMONERNAME', {headers: head});

  }

  function getStats(){

    return axios.get('https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/SUMMONERID/summary?season=SEASON2017', {headers: head});

  }

  axios.all([getSummoner(), getStats()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (summoner, stats) {
    res.json(summoner.data)
    res.json(stats.data)
  }));
});
```

I'm learning at the minute, so may be completely wrong here but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send response once.
Currently you are sending `res.json(); res.json()` twice.
It's not working like that. You can see error log in nodejs console.

Remember: One request, one response.

You have to send it only once like below

`res.json([summoner.data, stats.data])`